# How could I use the have+p.p in sentence?

Tags: word-usage, present-perfect, time

Hi I am curious about the usage "have +p.p"
So I tried make some example. But I'm not sure which is wrong or right.

1. I have experienced since 7 years at Microsoft as engineer.
2. I have more than 7 years of experience at Microsoft as engineer.
3. I have been working at Microsoft as engineer, more than 7 years
4. I have been working at Microsoft as engineer since 7 years.

Would you please let me know what exactly the usage of have+p.p?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present perfect tense (**have + *p.p.***) indicates that the action occurred within a time interval that ends in the present. **Since** indicates the start of the time interval. **For** indicates the duration of the time interval.

So, you would say:

> I have worked at Microsoft **for** seven years.
>
> I have worked at Microsoft **since** 2008.

You can use **ago** to subtract a duration from now to indicate the start of the time interval, which **since** needs, like this:

> I have worked at Microsoft **since** seven years **ago**.

"Seven years ago" means the point in time that was seven years before now.

Comment: Thanks but I have confused that we know the this one "have been ~ing" I am confusing between "have been ing" and " have p.p" . They are look the same.

Comment: @Carter You're not the only one! I just answered [a question about that](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/49339/6700) earlier today. See if that clarifies the difference.